# Posting an arbitrary amount of text areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm working in ASP.NET MVC3 in C#.

I have a table in my database containing questions. Admin's can add new questions, edit questions, etc.

I have another table that stores questions with answers (so the responses).

Example:

Question Table:

> QuestionId..........Question
>
> .......1..............How are you?
>
> .......2.........Why is the sky blue?

In my view I say "For every question, print the question and provide a text area to answer the question"

Then I want to say "When they submit, save every question and answer pair to the question and answer table"

Answer table:

> AnswerId........Question........Answer
>
> ......1.........How are you?......I'm fine
>
> ......2....Why is the sky blue?...Because

The problem is there is an arbitrary/variable amount of questions, and therefore there's an arbitrary number of text areas. How do I pass that information to the Post action?

**EDIT**

Here is my view after Xander's reccommendation

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("QuestionsAndAnswers", "Product"))
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var m in Model.Questions)
    {
    i++;
    <div>@m.Body</div>
    @Html.TextArea(string.Format("textareas[{0}]", i))
    <br />
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Home");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models:

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class AnswersViewModel
{
    public IList<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class AnswersController : Controller
{
    QuestionRepository _questionRepository = new QuestionRepository();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        AnswersViewModel model = new AnswersViewModel();
        model.Answers = new List<Answer>();
        IEnumerable<Question> questions = _questionRepository.GetRandomQuestions();
        foreach (Question question in questions)
        {
            model.Answers.Add(new Answer() { QuestionText = question.QuestionText });
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(AnswersViewModel model)
    {
        //the model will be properly bound here
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Views/Answers/Index.cshtml

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.AnswersViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Answers", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Answers)
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Views/Answers/EditorTemplates/Answer.cshtml

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Answer
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.QuestionText)
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.QuestionText)
<br />
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.AnswerText)
<br />
```

**Edit:**

I updated the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Wow! I appreciate this a whole lot. But I think there was a slight miscommunication and that's probably my fault. The questions table holds only questions. The answers table hold both questions and answers. But the questions and answers are initially `null`. When an answer is filled out, the question is sent with it ans stored in the answers table. This is to ensure that if a question is edited in the questions table, the old question will remain in the answers table. So if the admin changes "How are you?" to "Do you like bananas?" it won't also display as "Do you like bananas? I'm fine".

Comment: Hopefully that makes more sense. Because right now the way this is set-up it only allows for 1 answer per question. I need unlimited answers for a single question

Comment: There was no miscommunication. I only showed how to post the `Answers`, but I called the class `QuestionWithAnswer`. You can have a `Questions` table which you will use to load the questions from.

Comment: Thanks David. This works beautifully. I'll accept your answer and award you the bounty. You deserve it! Again I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 2):

Using your view....

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("QuestionsAndAnswers", "Product"))
{

    foreach (var m in Model.Questions)
    {
    <div class="formfields">
    <input type="hidden" name="QuestionId" id="QuestionId" value="@m.QuestionId" />
    <div>@m.Body</div>
    <textarea name="Answer" id="Answer"></textarea>
    </div>
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Home");
}
```

Here is Jquery for that....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.serializeObject = function () {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function () {
            if (o[this.name]) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Submit").click(function () {
            var QuestionAnswerArray = [];
            var QuestionAnswerLength = $(".formfield").length;
            $(".formfield").each(function (i) {
                var test = $(this).find("textarea, input").serializeObject()
                QuestionAnswerArray.push(test);
                if ((i + 1) == QuestionAnswerLength) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/../Product/QuestionsAndAnswers',
                        data: JSON.stringify(QuestionAnswerArray),
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (return_flag) {                            
                            if (return_flag == true) {
                                alert("Question and Answers Saved Succesfully!");                                
                            } else {
                                alert("Error Occured");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and you action in Controller....

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult QuestionsAndAnswers(Answers[] answers)
{
                foreach (var item in answers)
                {
                    // do whatever you want here
                }
                return View();
}
```

Comment: @Johannes, you can try the above solution, which i have used for masterdetails in asp.net mvc3..

Comment: I really do appreciate the help and the attempt. However I don't wish to meddle with JQuery if I don't have to. But +1 for the time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We can write our controller to receive arrays from model or viewmodels, but array is not ORM-friendly(if you plan to use your domain models to views directly). With that in mind, our Controller's View shall operate on `IList`; `IList` is flexible, it's not constrained by number of elements, unlike arrays; and IList is ORM-ready compared to array.

The only adjustment we should make is in view; HTML or rather javascript, doesn't have notion of list, it can only use an array or associative array. Acknowledging this limitation, we will emit those items from `List<ClassType>` to javascript-friendly arrays.

Finally, when we submit, our friendly neighborhood ASP.NET MVC will take care of these matters for us, i.e. it can automatically populate our `List<ClassType>` variables based on the submitted arrays from HTML/javascript, i.e. there is no need for us to iterate the `Request.Form`, no need for manual population, everything our code operates on is Model/ViewModel-centric as they are ought to be. ASP.NET MVC coders' life is wonderful isn't it? ;-)

Complete code below:

---

Model:

```
namespace SoQna.Models
{
    public class Question
    {
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    }

    public class Answer
    {
        public int AnswerId { get; set; }
        public Question Question { get; set; }
        public string AnswerText { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SoQna.ViewModels
{
    public class QnaViewModel
    {
        public IList<AnswerToQuestion> Answers { get; set; }
    }

    public class AnswerToQuestion
    {
        public int ToQuestionId { get; set; }
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public string AnswerText { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SoQna.Controllers
{
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    IList<SoQna.Models.Question> _qnaRepo = new List<SoQna.Models.Question>
    {
      new SoQna.Models.Question { QuestionId = 1, 
        QuestionText = 
          "Why is there a proliferation of different kind of ORMs?" 
      },
      new SoQna.Models.Question { 
          QuestionId = 2, QuestionText = "How are you?" 
      },
      new SoQna.Models.Question { 
          QuestionId = 3, QuestionText = "Why the sky is blue?" 
      },          
      new SoQna.Models.Question { 
          QuestionId = 4, QuestionText = "Why is MVC the bees knees?" 
      },          
    };


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      var qna = new SoQna.ViewModels.QnaViewModel { 
          Answers = new List<SoQna.ViewModels.AnswerToQuestion>() 
      };

      foreach (var question in _qnaRepo)
      {
        if (question.QuestionId == 1) continue; // subjective :-)

        qna.Answers.Add(
          new SoQna.ViewModels.AnswerToQuestion { 
              ToQuestionId = question.QuestionId, 
              QuestionText = question.QuestionText, 
              AnswerText = "Put your answer here" 
          }
        );         
      }

      return View(qna);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult SubmitAnswers(SoQna.ViewModels.QnaViewModel a)
    {
      foreach (var answer in a.Answers)
      {
        answer.QuestionText = _qnaRepo.Single(x => 
           x.QuestionId == answer.ToQuestionId).QuestionText;
      }
      return View(a);
    }

  }//HomeController
}//namespace
```

View for Home/Index

```
@model SoQna.ViewModels.QnaViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Hahah</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitAnswers", "Home"))
{


    int i = 0;
    foreach (var answer in Model.Answers)
    {
        @: Question #@(answer.ToQuestionId) <br />

        @Html.Hidden("Answers[" + i + "].ToQuestionId", answer.ToQuestionId)

        @Html.Label("Answers[" + i + "].QuestionText", answer.QuestionText)

        @* 
           to save bandwidth we didn't include QuestionText on submit, 
           this is done by assigning it on Label, and no need to persist 
           QuestionText on Hidden 
        *@

        <br />

        @Html.TextArea("Answers[" + i + "].AnswerText", answer.AnswerText)

        <hr />

        ++i;

    }

    <input type="submit" value="Done" />
}
```

View for Home/SubmitAnswers

```
@model SoQna.ViewModels.QnaViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SubmitAnswers";
}

<h2>SubmitAnswers</h2>


@foreach (var item in Model.Answers)
{
    @: Answer to question: @item.QuestionText
    <br />    
    @item.AnswerText

    <hr />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to build hidden field, something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="questionsAndAnswers" 
value="[{'id':questionId, 'question':questionName, 'answer':answerName}, 
        {'id':questionId, 'question':questionName, 'answer':answerName}...] />
```

Then you serialize posted hidden value